# Python 2D list to add the values of a column

Tags: python

So I have to use the function def sumColumn(matrix, columnIndex) to add the values of the columns created by the rows entered by the user, and I can't quite figure out what to do from this point.

```
def sumColumn(matrix, columnIndex):
    return

def getMatrix():
    matrix = []
    for row in range(3):
        print("Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row:%d" %row)
        row = input().split(' ')
        row = [float(i) for i in row]
        matrix.append(row)
    return matrix

def display(m):
    for row in m:
        print(row)

def main():
    m = getMatrix()
    print("\nThe matrix is")
    display(m)
    print()
    for col in range(len(m[0])):
        print("Sum of elements for column %d is %.2f" % (col, sumColumn(m,col)))

main()
```

Comment: Please format your code properly (with four leading spaces) and add a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `numpy`, you could use `.sum()` on the column

```
import numpy as np
def sumColumn(matrix, columnIndex):
    matrix = np.array(matrix)
    return matrix[:,columnIndex].sum()
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row:0
'1 2 3 4'
Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row:1
'1 2 3 4'
Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row for row:2
'1 2 3 4'

The matrix is
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]

Sum of elements for column 0 is 3.00
Sum of elements for column 1 is 6.00
Sum of elements for column 2 is 9.00
Sum of elements for column 3 is 12.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sumColumn(matrix, columnIndex):
    sum = 0                     # running sum
    for row in matrix:
        sum += row[columnIndex] # add value from specified column of row to sum
    return sum
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Comment: What more would you have me add?  What information is missing?  What makes you think it is a guess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function and a generator expression to get the element at that index from each of the rows in the matrix:

```
def sumColumn(matrix, columnIndex):
    return sum(row[columnIndex] for row in matrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

You never controlled that every row had same number of columns, and that could lead to later bugs.

Assuming the input was correct, you could just do:

```
def sumColumn(matrix, columnIndex):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        sum += matrix[i][columnIndex]
    return sum
```

But, please always double control input !